# Where should a UIButton be to add cells to a tableView?

Tags: buttons, ios, ipad, space-constraints

I have a limited amount of space in a new options menu I designed (much like a combination of twitter's scrollViewTexturedBackGround colored table, with notification center's custom headers, and Facebook's view dragging).

I want to be able to include the option to add new cells to the table, but have no idea where to put the button.

My current implementation has the user select the header of the section they want to add a cell in, but I'm worried this is too confusing and harmful to the workflow (each cell represents a 'binder' of files).  I can't place options in the UINavigationBar because it is full as it is, and will get cluttered with anymore added buttons.

Does anyone have any recommendations as to how or if I should include a UI element to add rows to the table?

Comment: can you add a screenshot ?

Comment: Can they add new rows in line or just at the bottom?  If it's just at the bottom, then a floating + button that appears when the user's mousing over the table would be nice.  If they can add them in line, maybe a floating + button to the right of the currently-hovered row to add below or above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You refer "cells" as well as "rows" - I presume both are same from your context (ideal scenario)

If you have space at the bottom or if even if there is a vertical scroll, "**Add a row**" button  or "**+**" sign under the table - just centered at mid-axis. This will be to add a complete row at the bottom.